# Failed to add 'Admin user' to %2% user group in Oracle 19C Windows 10 installation

Tags: installation, windows-10, oracle-19c

Oracle 19c installation fails with this error message.

I am trying to set up oracle for my '**Existing Local User**' account

Installation logs tries to add Admin user to all groups and fails .it says member does not exist.

**Installation logs :**

Failed to add Windows user or Windows group "Admin user" to Windows group "USERS"

Failed to add Windows user or Windows group "Admin user" to Windows group "ORA_OraDB19Home1_SYSDG"

Failed to add Windows user or Windows group "Admin user" to Windows group "ORA_DBA" etc.,

SEVERE: PRCZ-1082 : Failed to add Windows user or Windows group "Admin user" to Windows group "ORA_DBA"

WSE-000031: Unable to add user to operating system group.

O/S-Error: (OS 1387) A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist

at oracle.cluster.impl.winsecurity.GroupImpl.doInternalAddGroupMember(GroupImpl.java:488)

Caused by: oracle.ops.mgmt.nativesystem.NativeException: WSE-000031: Unable to add user to operating system group.

Should I be doing anything different?

Comment: Did you run the install executable as an Administrator?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the admin user name without spaces in it?

Comment: Hi, There was an option to continue despite that error. Now installation is stuck at 36% with logs as [CloneDBCreationStep.executeImpl:823]  executing datapatch %ORACLE_HOME%\OPatch\datapatch.bat